# How to convert UTCSeconds to TimeString?

Tags: xml, xpath

How to Convert UTC Seconds to This format:

```
00 h, 00 min, 00 sec
```

This code won't work:

```
concat(floor(Duration/DurationUTC div 360) mod 24,' h ', 
       floor(Duration/DurationUTC div 60) mod 60,' min ',
       Duration/DurationUTC mod 60,' sec')
```

I'm using XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if your seconds are in a structure such as this:

```
<Duration><DurationUTC>84341</DurationUTC></Duration>
```

And if you are calling the XPath expression in the correct context.

But everytime you reach 24 hours, it becomes zero. Perhaps that's the error you are encountering. If you don't want that behaviour just remove the `mod` expression:

```
concat(
    floor(/Duration/DurationUTC div 3600),' h ', 
    floor(/Duration/DurationUTC div 60) mod 60,' min ',
    /Duration/DurationUTC mod 60,' sec')
```

Now, for the example above, it will generate:

```
23 h 25 min 41 sec
```

There is no number formatting in XPath 1.0 but if you want *padding* for two digits in the format you described `00 h, 00 min, 00 sec`, there is a **hack** you can use. It uses the converted result as a *predicate* to select or not the *node* where the value is stored, then gets *one* of the digits that are in the node, converts it to a `0` and uses that character for padding when the calculated values are less than 10:

```
concat(
    translate(substring(/Duration/DurationUTC[floor(/Duration/DurationUTC div 3600) < 10],1,1),'0123456789','0000000000'),
    floor(/Duration/DurationUTC div 3600),' h ', 
    translate(substring(/Duration/DurationUTC[floor(/Duration/DurationUTC div 60) mod 60 < 10],1,1),'0123456789','0000000000'),
    floor(/Duration/DurationUTC div 60) mod 60,' min ',
    translate(substring(/Duration/DurationUTC[floor(/Duration/DurationUTC mod 60) < 10],1,1),'0123456789','0000000000'),
    /Duration/DurationUTC mod 60,' sec'
)
```

Now, if you have:

```
<Duration><DurationUTC>3970</DurationUTC></Duration>
```

instead of:

```
1 h 6 min 10 sec
```

you get:

```
01 h 06 min 10 sec
```

Comment: thank for the answer. This solution works sometimes: for example: if DurationUTC is 386, the result is 1 h 6 min 26 sec. [Start Time is 18-Dec-13 17:21:13 and end time is 18-Dec-13 17:27:39]. Why does it happen?

Comment: But when DurationUTC is 22 result is 0 h 0 min 22 sec.

Comment: That's the expected result, isn't it? What did you expect as a result?

Comment: 22 sec is correct but  1 h 6 min 26 sec is not. it's 1 hours more than it should be.

Comment: Of course. 60 x 60 = 3600. Missing one zero. I fixed it in the code.